Error : Cannot Find native module 'ExpoSQLite'
Hello guys I am just trying to do simple crud operations in React-Native using SQLite database but I am encountering:

(NOBRIDGE) ERROR  Error: Cannot find native module 'ExpoSQLite' [Component Stack]
(NOBRIDGE) WARN  Route "./_layout.jsx" is missing the required default export. Ensure a React component is exported as default. [Component Stack]

Error again and again
I am using Expo SDK 52 as the framework and react native version 0.76
here are my _layout.jsx and index.jsx files
index.jsx file
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import * as Sqlite from 'expo-sqlite';


const db = Sqlite.openDatabaseSync('trial1.db');


const SignupScreen = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('');
  const setTable = () => {
    try {
      db.transaction((tx) => {
        tx.executeSql(
          "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trial (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, email VARCHAR(20),password VARCHAR(20));",
          [],
          () => {
            console.log("Table created successfully.");
          },
          (error) => {
            console.error("Error creating table: ", error);
          }
        );
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error setting up database: ", error);
    }
  };
  const saveData = () => {
    // Handle signup logic here
    try{
      db.transaction( tx =>{
        tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO trial(email,password) VALUES(?,?)",[email,password],
          (txObj,res) => {
            console.log(res);
          },
          (txObj,error) =>{
            console.log(error);
          }
        );
      });
    }catch(error){
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    setTable();
  }, []);


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Create an Account</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Email"
        value={email}
        onChangeText={setEmail}
        keyboardType="email-address"
        autoCapitalize="none"
        placeholderTextColor="#aaa"
      />
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Password"
        value={password}
        onChangeText={setPassword}
        secureTextEntry
        placeholderTextColor="#aaa"
      />
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Confirm Password"
        value={confirmPassword}
        onChangeText={setConfirmPassword}
        secureTextEntry
        placeholderTextColor="#aaa"
      />
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Sign Up</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Text style={styles.footerText}>
        Already have an account? <Text style={styles.link}>Log In</Text>
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#f8f8f8',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginBottom: 20,
    color: '#333',
  },
  input: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 50,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#ddd',
    borderRadius: 8,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    marginBottom: 15,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  button: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#6200ea',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: 8,
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  footerText: {
    marginTop: 20,
    color: '#666',
  },
  link: {
    color: '#6200ea',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});

export default SignupScreen


_layout.jsx file
import { Stack } from "expo-router";
import { SQLiteProvider } from "expo-sqlite";

export default function RootLayout() {
  return (
    
      <Stack>
        <SQLiteProvider databaseName="trial1.db">
        </SQLiteProvider>
      </Stack>

  );
}



Error: Cannot find native module 'ExpoSQLite' [Component Stack] in Expo React-Native App

Tried debugging several times using ORM but still didn't work.
